# Bootstrap model auto spinning icon issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

According to [this](http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/) tutorial i used auto spinning icon for my bootstrap model. when footer button click spinning icon started. after 3 second i want to stop spinning and display a new button or a `div` on model body. how to do it and where i missed coding?

```
BootstrapDialog.show({ 
            title: 'dialog header',
            message: 'my details',                 
            buttons: [{   
                label: 'Contact',
                autospin: true,
                action: function(dialogRef) {
                    dialogRef.enableButtons(false);
                    dialogRef.setClosable(false);    
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        dialogRef.enableButtons(true);
                        dialogRef.setClosable(true); 
                        autospin: false;  //??? error
                        //display new button or div on body
                    }, 3000); 

                }
            },  {
                label: 'Close',
                action: function(dialog) {
                    dialog.close();
                }                
            }]                                    
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> autospin: false;
> ```

This is the syntax that you can use in [**object initializers**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). You cannot use it to *change* an object.

The simplest approach here would be to manually remove the Bootstrap classes that add that spinning icon.

Put this code inside of your timeout callback function:

```js
$('.modal-dialog span.icon-spin').removeClass('glyphicon-asterisk icon-spin')
```